# How can I display this information in my tableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, plist

I'm building an app that needs to display certain information within a tableView, getting said information from a .plist file. In the plist file, there is a root file, which is an array. Each array item (which are all dictionaries) has 4 items inside them:

- Name (string)
- Ingredients (array)
- Steps (array)
- Comments

I need to make the tableView have only a single label, displaying the text from the "Name" string. The other items will be used later.

How can I do this? I will gladly provide more information if necessary.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can set value from `plist` to `label` in your `tableview`:
place the code in

method:`- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

```
NSString* plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Exercise" ofType:@"plist"];
exerciseArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

label.text =[[exerciseArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"Name"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Take custom class for `UITableViewCell` and design as per your requirement. Then take data from `plist` file. Assign data to `CustomTableViewCell` in `CellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Answer (score -1):

First you need to get the path of your plist file from NSBundle. Then store the elements in an array and populate the label with the elements of array at indexpath.row for key "name". Hope this helps.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Menu" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableArray *menuArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile : path];
nameLabel.text = [[menuArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey: @"name"];
```